# Issue with new/delete with SecureZeroMemory

Tags: c++, winapi, new-operator, delete-operator, securezeromemory

Can anyone help me understand why my code is failing on delete[] szPassword in the first block of code? I know that szPassword is only copying "a", and st2 is equal to 8:

```
TCHAR *szPassword = new TCHAR[2]();
StringCchCopy(szPassword, 2, L"ab");
SIZE_T st2 = sizeof(szPassword);
SecureZeroMemory(szPassword, st2);
delete[] szPassword;
```

However, when this is run, without getting the sizeof() value, it works fine:

```
TCHAR *szPassword = new TCHAR[2]();
StringCchCopy(szPassword, 2, L"ab");
SecureZeroMemory(szPassword, 2);
delete[] szPassword;
```

Comment: Did you check what value `sizeof(szPassword);` gives you? (Hint: It's highly unlikely to be 2)

Comment: Yes, st2 is equal to 8.

Comment: So obviously your call to `SecureZeroMemory` ends up writing past the bounds of the array, invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: It could, yes, but the code errors out on delete[] szPassword in the first example.

Comment: Not "could", but *does*. Do you know what undefined behavior means?

Comment: *undefined behavior* means that **anything** can happen. In your case it seems that you are lucky and the compiler catches it at `delete[]` (which leads me to believe you are running this in debug mode)

Comment: Oh, I see! Duh, working too late. Thanks. So then the question is how do I use SZM to correctly zero out the block of memory with the correct size without passing the size of the string directly to it?

Comment: @JeffR, use `std::vector`, for example.

Comment: @UnholySheep - *and the compiler catches it* - really ? compiler ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

szPassword is a pointer, not an array and therefore `sizeof(szPassword)` will be 4 or 8. In a 64-bit application this is too much, you will attempt to write 8 bytes to a 4 byte buffer.

The C++ run-time is allowed to allocate more than you ask it to and it often does this so it can add special data to the end of the buffer so it can detect buffer overruns.

Do something like this instead:

```
const UINT charcount = 2;
TCHAR *szPassword = new TCHAR[charcount];
...
SecureZeroMemory(szPassword, charcount * sizeof(TCHAR));
delete[] szPassword;
```

If the buffer is always small-ish you can just use an array on the stack:

```
TCHAR szPassword[200];
...
SecureZeroMemory(szPassword, sizeof(szPassword));
```

Comment: So in this example, with szPassword[200], you're saying as long as the buffer is > 8, then sizeof() will work? If so, isn't that just zeroing out the memory of the first 4 or 8 bytes?

Comment: No, in the second example `szPassword` in an array, not a pointer. If you are compiling a Unicode application it will be 400 bytes in the second example. This is basic C stuff and you need to learn the difference between pointers and arrays.

Comment: `TCHAR a[20], *b = new TCHAR[20];` and try `sizeof` on both of those.